# Como converter o Sender para um Form?

Tags: c#, winforms

No meu programa, preciso que a seguinte rotina funcione:

```
private void FuncaoTal()
{
  frmSelecao.FormClosing += atualizarEvento;
  SplitContMenu.Panel2.Controls.Clear();
  splitContMenu.Panel2.Controls.Add(frmSelecao);
  frmSelecao.Show();
}
private void atualizarEvento(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (ContaAtiva.id == 0)
   {
     sender(as Form).FormClosed += carregarLogoVanguarda;
   }
   else
   {
     sender(as Form).FormClosed += acessarMenuMovimentacoes;
   }
}
public void acessarMenuMovimentacoes(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmMenuMovimentacao frm = new frmMenuMovimentacao();
        frm.AutoScroll = true;
        frm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        frm.TopLevel = false;
        splitContMenu.Panel2.Controls.Clear();
        splitContMenu.Panel2.Controls.Add(frm);
        frm.FormClosed += carregarLogoVanguarda;
        if (ContaAtiva.id > 0)
        {
            frm.Show();
        }
    }
private void carregarLogoVanguarda(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox picBoxLogo = new PictureBox();
        picBoxLogo.Image = global::InterfaceVisual.Properties.Resources.Logo_Vanguarda;
        picBoxLogo.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        picBoxLogo.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage;
        picBoxLogo.BackColor = Color.White;
        splitContMenu.Panel2.Controls.Clear();
        splitContMenu.Panel2.Controls.Add(picBoxLogo);
    }
```

Não estou conseguindo fazer com que a rotina atualizar evento funcione.

A minha intenção é que, quando o usuário selecionar uma conta na tela de seleção, a tela seja fechada e no lugar dela uma outra seja aberta. Senão, ele carreja a tela inicial de novo.

P.s: Estou usando `SplitContainer`. As telas são carregadas no `panel 2` dele.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está usando a sintaxe errada. O certo é:

```
sender as Form
```

`sender(as Form)` seria uma tentativa de chamar `sender` como uma função, e depois um erro feio de compilação porque o compilador não faz ideia do que fazer com `as Form`, ainda mais usá-lo como parâmetro.

Comment: Só complementando a sua resposta, a sintaxe ficaria:                                             *(Sender as Form).FormClosed += carregarLogoVanguarda;*

Answer (score 0):

Seu código tem um problema de box / unboxing.

veja: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/yz2be5wk.aspx

```
if (ContaAtiva.id == 0)
{
  (Form)sender.FormClosed += carregarLogoVanguarda;
}
else
{
  (Form)sender.FormClosed += acessarMenuMovimentacoes;
}
```